# The number of matches in a competition

Tags: combinatorics

In a competition there were 10 players , each player plays 4 matches , how many matches in the whole competition ?

My attempt is : $C^{10}_{3}$

Is it correct ?

Comment: No.  How did you arrive at that?

Comment: No.  Consider describing this as a graph with ten vertices representing the players with the games being represented by the edges.  "Each player plays 4 matches" corresponds to the vertices all being of degree $4$.  Now, apply the "handshaking lemma" and conclude.

Comment: How can i find the sum of the edges ? @JMoravitz

Comment: *Handshaking Lemma*

Comment: Is says that the sum equals $2\times $ the number of edges , so how can i get the number of edges @JMoravitz

Comment: $\sum\limits_{v\in V}\text{deg}(v) = 2|E|$, note that $\text{deg}(v)=4$ for all vertices (*as per the phrase "each player plays 4 matches"*) so this is $\sum\limits_{v\in V}4=2|E|$ which simplifies to $4|V|=2|E|$.  We know $|V|=10$ since there are ten players... so we have $4\times 10 = 2\times |E|$...  You ask how to get the number of edges?  *Divide by two*

Comment: This means the number of matches is $2\times 20$ = 40 , is not it ? @JMoravitz

Comment: 4 times 10 is 40.   4 times 10 divided by 2 is only 20.

Comment: Somehow you took my "$4\times 10 = 2\times |E|$.  *Divide by two*" comment... divided the first term by two but then *also multiplied the second term by two for no reason!*  If you are unable to solve for $x$ in $4\times 10 = 2\times x$... then you frankly should not be in whatever class you are now and should be in remedial algebra lessons.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of solving this problem without knowing anything about combinations or graph theory is to suppose that each player wins half their matches. Then the total number of wins is $10\times 2 = 20$ and so there are precisely $20$ matches.